# OutOfBoundsException - Why?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've had a read on the forum around OutofBoundException error but I am still none the wiser on my issue unfortunately.

```
String[] expected = new String[10];
    //{"Acapulco","Frankfurt","London","New York","Paris","Portland","San Francisco","Seattle","Sydney","Zurich"};
    expected[0] = "Acapulco";
    expected[1] = "Frankfurt";
    expected[2] = "London";
    expected[3] = "New York";
    expected[4] = "Paris";
    expected[5] = "Portland";
    expected[6] = "San Francisco";
    expected[7] = "Seattle";
    expected[8] = "Sydney";
    expected[9] = "Zurich";

    List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.name("fromPort"));

 // match the fromPort list value against the expected Array
    for (int i = 0  ; i < (expected.length); i++) {

         String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");

         if (optionValue.equals(expected[i])) {
             System.out.println("PASSED on: " + optionValue + " we had: "+ expected[i] );
         } 

         else {
             System.out.println("FAILED on: " + optionValue + " we expected: " + expected[i]);
         }
 }
    //close Firefox
    driver.close();
```

The above is the code but when executing I am getting:

```
Test Passed! - Correct Landing Page
PASSED on: Acapulco we had: Acapulco
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at mypackage.myclass.main(myclass.java:71)
```

No idea, so any help would be appreciated. Btw fairly new to Java and Selenium

Comment: it seems that `allOptions` has only one entry in it. Modify your loop condition to `i < (expected.length) && i < allOptions.size()`

Comment: `allOptions` is a `List` with one element. The first time through the loop, you have `allOptions.get(0)`, which works. The second time through the loop, you have `allOptions.get(1)`, which is past the end of the list.

Comment: Okay so doing that has got rid of the OOBE - fantastic great. But as khelwood has said - it only appears to loop once.... any ideas?

Comment: Open a new topic for a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is when you fetch the allElements list:

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.name("fromPort"));
```

You are only getting one element in this request

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

When `i = 1` in:

```
String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");
```

[`IOBException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) occurs...

Check your request or your `for` condition to check both lists:

```
for (int i = 0  ; i < (expected.length) && i < allOptions.size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to check your loop counter which you use as index of a list be compare to size of another list. It is completely error prone.