# For loop not only passing once

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver

```
      String[] expected = new String[10];
    //{"Acapulco","Frankfurt","London","New York","Paris","Portland","San Francisco","Seattle","Sydney","Zurich"};
    expected[0] = "Acapulco";
    expected[1] = "Frankfurt";
    expected[2] = "London";
    expected[3] = "New York";
    expected[4] = "Paris";
    expected[5] = "Portland";
    expected[6] = "San Francisco";
    expected[7] = "Seattle";
    expected[8] = "Sydney";
    expected[9] = "Zurich";

    List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.name("fromPort"));


 // match the fromPort list value against the expected Array
    for (int i = 0  ; i < (expected.length) && i < allOptions.size(); i++) {

         String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");

         if (optionValue.equals(expected[i])) {
             System.out.println("PASSED on: " + optionValue + " we had: "+ expected[i] );
         } 

         else {
             System.out.println("FAILED on: " + optionValue + " we expected: " + expected[i]);
         }
 }
    //close Firefox
    driver.close();
```

When executing the loop is only going round once then it exists... So it executes: 
    PASSED on: Acapulco we had: Acapulco
then exits the loop...

This is following on from my other comment: [My Other Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888117/outofboundsexception-why/30888436#30888436)

New to all this Java and Selenium....

I am assuming its something to do with the Size of it only being 1; but not sure how to increase/overcome this

HTML snippet added as requested in comments:

```
<tr>

<td align="right">
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
        <b>

            Departing 
                          From: 

        </b>
    </font>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="fromPort">
        <option value="Acapulco"></option>
        <option value="Frankfurt"></option>
        <option value="London"></option>
        <option value="New York"></option>
        <option value="Paris"></option>
        <option value="Portland"></option>
        <option value="San Francisco"></option>
        <option value="Seattle"></option>
        <option value="Sydney"></option>
        <option value="Zurich"></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Have you tried printing size of the list `allOptions`?

Comment: Yes its prints 1 - which is whats leading me to belive thats the culprit - but as mentioned not sure on this. But then again it could be 1 as its "first in the loop"?

Comment: Try printing that before the loop, though the result will be same. Will need the html snippet.

Comment: Yes its still prints 1

Comment: Please post the html.

Comment: Ive posted in the main question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code to select all options. The code you are trying to use selects the select element itself and not the options.

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElement(By.name("fromPort")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

Comment: When trying to replace with the above code, i get "Invalid Character constant" and when trying to execute "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid character constant"

Comment: Ah, change to double quotes on "option" and hey presto! many thanks